# Key:Value of Dictionary is not getting inserted once it is popped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to check whether a Graph remains cyclic after deleting a node. In that attempt, I am popping a key and checking whether removing that node removes all the cycles or not. But perhaps after the first pop, the popped element is not getting inserted

```
def detectCycle(v,visited,parent):
    visited[v]=True
    for i in Graph[v]:
        if(visited[i]==False):
            if(detectCycle(i,visited,v)):
                return True
        elif parent!=i:
            return True
    return False

def isCyclic():
    visited=[False for i in range(N+1)]
    for i in Graph.keys():
        if(visited[i]==False):
            if(detectCycle(i,visited,-1)==True):
                return True
    return False


Graph={1: [5, 2], 2: [5, 1, 3, 4], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [1, 2]}
N=len(Graph.keys())
flag=0
for i in range(1,N+1):            
        x=Graph.pop(i)
        if(isCyclic()):
            pass
        else:
            flag=1
            break
        Graph[i]=x
if(flag==1):
        print(i)
else:
        print(-1)
```

I expect the node removing which the cycle is removed and if there exists no such node -1 is returned however what I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for i in Graph[v]:
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'N' is not defined` - please provide a working example which yields the error in your description!

Comment: It is also not clear why you are declaring either one of those global variables in function `isCyclic`.

Comment: I have added the changes @goodvibration please give it a check

Answer (score 0):

The line `x = Graph.pop(i)` where i=1(first iteration) removes the key(1) from the
dictionary. This is why you are getting the key error.
Try using `x = Graph[i]` instead?
Or if you need the logic of getting -1 if key dosnt exist - use:
`x = Graph.get(i, -1)`

Comment: I wanted to actually remove the node and check whether there still remains a cycle, so by popping I wanted to remove the node and check whether there remains a cycle if there remains a cycle then that node was not part of the cycle so I add it back to the graph, that was my motive

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario.
You removed the key `1` from the `Graph`, and iterating over the rest of the dictionary.
`Graph[2]` has value `[5,1,3,4]`
Now you are iterating over `[5,1,3,4]` and checking the Graph with those keys
`Graph[5]` has value `[1,2]`
Now iterating over `[1,2]` and checking the Graph with those keys will give you a `KeyError` as `Graph[1]` doesn't exist.
I made a change to the function `detectCycle` to check if the key exists. *Also made a change to return the called function based on the comment.*

```
Graph={1: [5, 2], 2: [5, 1, 3, 4], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [1, 2]}
def detectCycle(v,visited,parent):
    visited[v]=True
    if v in Graph:
        for i in Graph[v]:
            if(visited[i]==False):
                return detectCycle(i,visited,v)
            elif parent!=i:
                return True
    return False

def isCyclic():
    visited=[False for i in range(N+1)]
    for i in Graph.keys():
        if(visited[i]==False):
            return detectCycle(i,visited,-1)
    return False

N=len(Graph.keys())
flag=0
for i in range(1,N+1):            
    x=Graph.pop(i)
    if(isCyclic()):
        pass
    else:
        flag=1
        break
    Graph[i]=x

if(flag==1):
    print(i)
else:
    print(-1)
```

Comment: No, I wanted to print the node removing which there remain no more cycles in the graph, in the given case as you can see 5-1-2 forms a cycle, so when we start traversing if we remove node 1 from the graph there remains no more cycle, obviously removing 5 or 2 also removes the cycle but since 1 occurs first while traversing the output would be 1

Comment: In that case, you should be returning the function `return detectCycle(i,visited,v)` instead of checking if it is true. See the changed code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation though why I was getting the error. I have fixed the error.

Comment: @MasterMind If this solved your problem, please, choose as the answer.